# WP8 To Do list data template

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In WP 8 calender app, there is a 'To-Do list' section which looks as shown below. It is clear that they are using Pivot control here.

[image]

However, when we click on 'select' button, we get a new screen with list of items which can be checked to perform 'delete' activity.

[image]

What exactly is happening when user clicks on 'Select' button ?

1. Is user navigated to new page (Image 2)

OR

2. Does other two pivotitems (day, agenda) get disabled and UI is updated to reflect a list of items which can be checked to perform 'delete' activity.

I want to implement the same behaviour in my app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is just have something like this

```
<StackPanle>
    <Checkbox Visibility={Binding SomeProperty} IsChecked={Binding SomethingElse}/>
    <Label Content={Binding SomeOtherProperty}/>
</StackPanel>
```

By clicking the button you just toggle SomeProperty from `Visibility.Visible` to `Visibility.Collapsed` and that's it. If the property `SomethingElse` is checked for any of the items you just enable other buttons like `Delete`, `Move`, `Foo`

Edit:
I see no reason why you couldn't change visibility at runtime. Just have well defined criterie which alter your visibility properties in the view model.

To alter the icons at the bottom you need to do something like this

```
public partial class YourView
{
    private ApplicationBarIconButton _icon;
    public YourView()
    {
          _icon = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        if (SomeSavedState)
        {
            _icon.IconUri = new Uri("somePicture.png", UriKind.Relative);
            _icon.Text = "Delete";
        }
        else
        {
            _icon.IconUri = new Uri("someOtherPicture.png", UriKind.Relative);
            _icon.Text = "Select";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. However, is it possible to alter visibility of pivot items and dynamically change app bar buttons at run time ?

Any idea what exactly WP team did here?

Answer (score 2):

@IvanCrojachKaračić gave a good answer.

And if you want dynamically change app bar buttons at run time you can do this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
  <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="appbar1"
                        IsVisible="True">
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abMain1"
                                    IconUri="/icons/appbar.favs.addto.rest.png"
                                    Text="blabla1" />
  </shell:ApplicationBar>

  <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="appbar2"
                        IsVisible="True">
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abMain2"
                                    IconUri="/icons/appbar.favs.addto.rest.png"
                                    Text="blabla2" />
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abMain3"
                                    IconUri="/icons/appbar.cancel.rest.png"
                                    Text="blabla3" />
  </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And then change it from code:

```
 ApplicationBar = (Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar) Resources["appbar1"];
```

and

```
 ApplicationBar = (Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar) Resources["appbar2"];
```

You can big numbers of different `AppBars`. 
Hope its help.

Answer (score 0):

just using LongListMultiSelector and set the property IsSelectionEnabled to true 
its a toolkit element